# SQL Query: Search with list of tuples

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a following table (simplified version) in SQLServer.

```
Table Events
-----------------------------------------------------------
| Room | User | Entered             | Exited              |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| A    | Jim  | 2014-10-10T09:00:00 | 2014-10-10T09:10:00 | 
| B    | Jim  | 2014-10-10T09:11:00 | 2014-10-10T09:22:30 | 
| A    | Jill | 2014-10-10T09:00:00 | NULL                | 
| C    | Jack | 2014-10-10T09:45:00 | 2014-10-10T10:00:00 | 
| A    | Jack | 2014-10-10T10:01:00 | NULL                |
 .
 .
 .
```

I need to create a query that returns person's whereabouts in given timestamps.
For an example: Where was (Jim at 2014-10-09T09:05:00), (Jim at 2014-10-10T09:01:00), (Jill at 2014-10-10T09:10:00), ...

The result set must contain the given User and Timestamp as well as the found room (if any).

```
------------------------------------------
| User | Timestamp           | WasInRoom |
------------------------------------------
| Jim  | 2014-10-09T09:05:00 | NULL      |
| Jim  | 2014-10-09T09:01:00 | A         |
| Jim  | 2014-10-10T09:10:00 | A         |
```

The number of User-Timestamp tuples can be > 10 000.

The current implementation retrieves all records from Events table and does the search in Java code. I am hoping that I could push this logic to SQL. But how?

I am using MyBatis framework to create SQL queries so the tuples can be inlined to the query.

Comment: How you are planning to pass the tuples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic query is:

```
select e.*
from events e
where e.user = 'Jim' and '2014-10-09T09:05:00' >= e.entered and ('2014-10-09T09:05:00' <= e.exited or e.exited is NULL) or
      e.user = 'Jill' and '2014-10-10T09:10:00 >= e.entered and ('2014-10-10T09:10:00' <= e.exited or e.exited is NULL) or
     . . .;
```

SQL Server can handle ridiculously large queries, so you can continue in this vein.  However, if you have the name/time values in a table already (or it is the result of a query), then use a `join`:

```
select ut.*, t.*
from usertimes ut left join
     events e
     on e.user = ut.user and 
        ut.thetime >= et.entered and (ut.thetime <= exited or ut.exited is null);
```

Note the use of a `left join` here.  It ensures that all the original rows are in the result set, even when there are no matches.

Answer (score 1):

Answers from Jonas and Gordon got me on track, I think.

Here is query that seems to do the job:

```
CREATE TABLE #SEARCH_PARAMETERS(User VARCHAR(16), "Timestamp" DATETIME)
INSERT INTO #SEARCH_PARAMETERS(User, "Timestamp") 
VALUES 
('Jim', '2014-10-09T09:05:00'),
('Jim', '2014-10-10T09:01:00'),
('Jill', '2014-10-10T09:10:00')

SELECT #SEARCH_PARAMETERS.*, Events.Room FROM #SEARCH_PARAMETERS
LEFT JOIN Events
ON #SEARCH_PARAMETERS.User = Events.User AND
   #SEARCH_PARAMETERS."Timestamp" > Events.Entered AND
   (Events.Exited IS NULL OR Events.Exited > #SEARCH_PARAMETERS."Timestamp"

DROP TABLE #SEARCH_PARAMETERS
```

Comment: You could amend the time window part of your filter to: `#SEARCH_PARAMETERS."Timestamp" Between Events.Entered AND coalesce(Events.Exited,#SEARCH_PARAMETERS."Timestamp")`

Answer (score 0):

By declaring a table valued parameter type for the (user, timestamp) tuples, it should be simple to write a table valued user defined function which returns the desired result by joining the parameter table and the Events table. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Since you are using MyBatis it may be easier to just generate a table variable for the tuples inline in the query and join with that.